# DDWRT Iptable as a global rule?

Tags: linux, router, dd-wrt

```
iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -p udp -s 192.168.0.62 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 23.21.182.24
```

Instead of only rerouting traffic from 192.168.0.62, I'd like to reroute traffic from all ips, 192.168.0.*, possible?

Comment: All to the same destination?   Try replacing `-s 192.168.0.62` with `-s 192.168.0.0/24`.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add to @Zoredache comment (Which is also an answer)

Extract of the Command `iptables` in relation to `-s` flag

> --source  -s [!] address[/mask]

So what @Zoredache has suggested works by working on the subnet mask short hand

To break down `-s 192.168.0.0/24` we need to look at the subnet mask it represents:

> 255.255.255.0

Now this doesn't really give us any indication of how it's represented as the number 24 until we look at the binary representation of the subnet mask:

> 11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000

Now a quick count will show that the first 24 binary switches are set to 1 this is why it's represented as /24

---

So what we have told the `iptables` command is that we want the source to be the first 256 (192.168.0.0-255) IP addresses starting at `192.168.0.0` to be declared as a source in this command

---

Another example would be I want the first 65,536 IP addresses starting at `10.1.0.0` to be the source

So the command would be `-s 10.1.0.0/16` this is subnet mask `255.255.0.0` (Binary is `11111111.11111111.00000000.00000000`) and this will declare `10.1.0.0` through `10.1.255.255` as the source addresses